# Difference between には...がある and は...がある

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

I would like to know which is the difference between には...がある and は...がある to express possession.

For example, which would be the difference between

> 彼には友人をつくる才能がある。

> 彼は友人をつくる才能がある。

Or between

> 彼には車が二台ある。

> 彼は車が二台ある。

Answer (score 2):

> 彼には友人をつくる才能がある

彼には才能があるが他の人にはないという区別や皮肉が表現できる。

> 彼は友人をつくる才能がある

事実のみを述べている。

> 彼には車が二台ある。

（すごい！普通の人は二台なんて買えないよ！）

> 彼は車が二台ある

（事実）

Comment: So, when putting には, does it mean that somebody has something that the rest don't usually have?

Comment: Which would be the difference in negative sentences? For example:  彼には子供がいない。(what nuance it has?) /  
彼は子供がいない。(this is just an statement, a fact)